# Remove elements from fullCalendar using qtip2

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, qtip2

I am currently trying to add a qtip2 to my fullCalendar window so I could display the qtip and have a link/button to remove the selected event on the calendar, unfortunately I am having trouble with that. Here is what my fullCalendar looks like:

```
$('#calendar_main').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView:'agendaWeek',
            minTime:8,
            height:600,
            maxTime:20,
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot:false,
            theme: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            selectable: true,
               selectHelper: true,

            eventRender: function(event, element) {
               element.qtip({ 
                content: "<a onlick='alert('Remove')> Remove me</a>",
                title: {
                  text: 'RDV',
                       button: false
                }
                },
                position: {
                    at: 'right-bottom'
                },
                show: {
                    solo: true
                },
                hide: false,
                style: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded'
               });
            } 
        });
```

I believe the issue sits within the content attribute of qtip, but not sure why this does not work. In this case I am just trying to display an alert, but it is not working (The Qtip displays, but when I click on "remove me", nothing happen. Once I get that working, I will be able to replace the Alert with my own JS function that will remove the selected event in my DB.

ps: I am working with Adobe Air, not sure if this could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you need to escape the single quotations to form the string in the alert.

And second, you forgot to close the alert with a single quote in the tag. Hope it helps...

```
'<a onlick="alert(\'Remove\');"> Remove me</a>'
```

This is how it should look.

Comment: Thanks Juan, unfortunately it still does not display the Alert box. I think I have found a workaround where I display a div instead and I put the call of my JS function directly in the div code. This is a ok solution for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

probably couse you are using call procedure for qTip but in real you are using qTip2. Use in real (source script) old version qTip 1.00xxx and all will be ok - I did do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually doing the same thing and I can remove it fine. The only issue I run into is when the event is destroyed the qtip sticks around so running into an issue where eventDestroy never gets called.

Anyway I call calendarEventRender:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            firstDay: 1,
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            allDaySlot: false,
            columnFormat: {
              week: 'ddd'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                calendarEventRender(event, element);
            }
        });
```

Here are my functions:

```
function calendarEventRender(event, element)
{
    element.qtip({
        content: {
            title: { text: event.title },
            text: '<button type="button" onclick="removeEvent(' + event.id + ')">Delete</button>'
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true
        },
        hide: {
            event: 'unfocus click'
        }
    });
}

function removeEvent(eventId, userId)
{    
    //Delete the event
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventId);
}
```

And it all seems to work. I don't have time to go through and grab your code, but hopefully this helps. Also in the future if you can get a http://jsfiddle.net/ of it up not working people can test and fix it a lot easier.

Hmm so I created a jsfiddleto test it all: http://jsfiddle.net/MusicMonkey5555/pZdyt/1/
and it seems to not work in there. My guess is that it is jquery or qtip or fullcalendar version. That is the one issue with jsfiddle is getting the correct version of everything.  The one I have working on my site are the following:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/1.6.4/fullcalendar.print.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.1/jquery.qtip.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.1/jquery.qtip.min.css
```

So I would suggestion trying to use those versions and see if it works. Most often it is because jquery has a bug and you need a different version.